# BizTalk 2016 Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Tags: sharepoint, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I'm running BizTalk 2016 Developer edition with Feature Pack 2 and CU3. I've configured a Receive location to pull from a SharePoint 2013 library but I'm seeing the following in the event log:

*The adapter "Windows SharePoint Services" raised an error message. Details "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.".*

The following suggests this should have been installed to the GAC as part of the BizTalk installation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/csom-sharepoint-services-adapter . I can't find the assembly on the BizTalk VM.

I've read that Windows Identity Foundation must be installed on the BizTalk Server if using SharePoint CSOM. Server manager was showing that it was installed, although the tick is in a grey box that can't be un-ticked. I ran the PS `Remove-WindowsFeature Windows-Identity-Foundation` and then added it again using Server Manager - it's now showing with a "full tick". Didn't fix the problem though :(

Anyone else hit this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by installing the SharePoint Client Components SDK from the following site: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35585

Be sure to restart the host instance of the receive location after installing.